# Ckeditor load templates from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ckeditor

I want to give the users the ability to set their own templates for use in the editor, the thing is that i don't exactly don't know how.

I created the table for the templates and did the php function to retrieve the data from the DB but i can't show it in the portal.

I saw this in other question:

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
        config.templates_files = ['js/editor/plugins/templates/templates/custom.js'];
    };

CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
    templates: 'my',
    on: {
        instanceReady: function( argument ) {
            var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
                CKEDITOR.addTemplates( 'my', {
                    templates: [
                        {
                            title: 'My Templates',
                            html: this.responseText
                        }
                    ]
                });
            };
            httpRequest.open( 'GET', 'in/ver.php?cons=8' );
            httpRequest.send();
        }
    }
});
```

But it doesn't seems to work in any way, and i can't find any documentation about it

Answer (score 0):

At the end i solved by overriding the action of the template button:

```
CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function (ev) {


        var editor = ev.editor;

var cargaPlantilla = new CKEDITOR.command(editor, {
            exec: function(editor){
                $( '#modal' ).fadeIn();
                $.post("in/ver.php?cons=8",{algo: "algo"},function(exito){
                    $("#modal").html(exito);
                });
                $( '#modal-background' ).fadeTo( 500, .5 );
            }
        });
ev.editor.commands.templates.exec = cargaPlantilla.exec;
    });
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```